# Cannot bind a given Map in a Form using Play for Scala

Tags: scala, playframework

I cannot bind a value into a Form[M]. It seems it doesn't work because of the List: if I turn List[String] into String, it works. Here's the code

```
case class SearchCriteria (
  val q: Option[String],
  var fq_chset: List[String]
)

val theSearchForm: Form[SearchCriteria] = Form(
  mapping(
    "q" -> optional(text),
    "fq_chset" -> list(text)
  )
)(SearchCriteria.apply _)(SearchCriteria.unapply _)

def foldSearchCriteria(searchForm: Form[SearchCriteria]): Either[Throwable, SearchCriteria] = {
  foldForm[SearchCriteria](searchForm, { searchCriteria =>
    Logger.debug(searchCriteria.toString())
    Right(searchCriteria)
  })
}

def foldForm[F](aForm: Form[F], onSuccess: F => Either[Throwable,F]): Either[Throwable,F] = {
  aForm.fold(
    hasErrors = { form => 
      Left(new RuntimeException("Errors while folding Form"))
    },
    success = { formData => 
     onSuccess(formData)
   } 
  )   
}
```

What I get is:

```
foldSearchCriteria(theSearchForm.bind(Map("q" -> "ValueQ")))
>> SearchForm( Some(ValueQ), None ) )


foldSearchCriteria(theSearchForm.bind(Map("fq_chset" -> "Value1")))
>> SearchForm( None, Some(List()) )
```

Any idea?

Comment: Is it really necessary to have an optional list, though? Would an empty list not suffice?

Comment: Ok, it would. But I don't expect it will fix the problem.

Comment: ... refactored from Option[List[String]] to List[String]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to bind list values, the key has to have list indices appended (e.g. `[0]`, `[1]`). Try this:

```
theSearchForm.bind(Map("fq_chset[0]" -> "Value1"))
```

Note: if you're binding from request data it's sufficient to just use `[]` as a suffix, but this doesn't work when binding from a map with string values because you need to disambiguate the keys.

You can also use `bindFromRequest` with a `Map[String,Seq[String]]` argument and you don't have to specify the exact indices:

```
theSearchForm.bindFromRequest(Map("fq_chset[]" -> Seq("Value1")))
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I was aware of the .bindFromRequest() method, what I needed was actually to bind a value declared in the code.